# How do I retrieve next value for multiple sequences in different rows in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am using this query

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME1 FROM DUMMY_TABLE UNION
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME2 FROM DUMMY_TABLE
```

This is not resulting the answer in multiple rows .
Suggest me some solution for this because I have to retrieve next value for thousands of sequences

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates, so if both sequences return the same value you only get one row. Try `UNION ALL` instead (but retrieving the next value for "thousands" of sequences sounds like a strange thing to do. What is the actual, **real** problem you are trying to solve?)

Comment: I have altered sequences in my Database I want to check whether they have been altered correctly or not . So I am retrieving the nextvalue for them to check whether any sequence got skipped from me to alter.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the catalog table to see if that change is reflected correctly...?

Comment: I am getting error while using union or union all in above queries- Nextval is not signified for this context.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your core question: You can check [SYSCAT.SEQUENCES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004203.html) for metadata about sequences.

The attributes / columns START and NEXTCACHEFIRSTVALUE are the ones of interest for you. Note that sequence values typically are cached for performance, so you need to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME1 FROM DUMMY_TABLE UNION ALL
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME2 FROM DUMMY_TABLE;
```

If the expressions return the same value, then `UNION` will return only one row -- it removes duplicates.

Comment: UNION ALL, UNION doesn't work with NEXT VALUE or seqname.NEXTVAL in db2

Comment: @coderzzz18 . . . Interesting.  Why would your original code work at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query

```
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME1)
,      (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME2)
```

although you won't know which row is which, so maybe this

```
VALUES ('SEQ1', NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME1)
,      ('SEQ2', NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCENAME2)
```